# How to save user password in Hash format into DB in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii-components, yii2

I need to create new user. And I want to save password into hash format in DB. But I failed several times.

Here is my code:

## Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new User();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

## User Model

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Security::validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
}


/**
 * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
 *
 * @param string $password
 */


public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Security::generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

## User Table Rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['c_authkey', 'inserttime'], 'required'],
        [['c_branch', 'c_roleid', 'c_active', 'c_status'], 'integer'],
        [['c_expdate', 'inserttime', 'updatetime'], 'safe'],
        [['username', 'c_desig', 'insertuser', 'updateuser'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['password'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
        [['c_authkey'], 'string', 'max' => 256],
        [['c_name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['c_cellno'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
        [['username'], 'unique']
    ];
}
```

What I am missing? what's the solution?

Comment: You have two return statements (is that a copy+paste error or part of your question?). Remove the first one as it is the one from the demo not using the security component.

Comment: It's a part of my question. I removed First one. But it is saving only static password like: 123.. How can I convert them in hash and save to db .. thanks

Comment: Then please edit the question to contain the code that is actually causing your problem

Comment: thanks. I have edited my question lines. it is saving only static password like: 123.. How can I convert them in hash and save to db. please

Comment: What is the name of your password field in the database?

Comment: @topher : password field name is password

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are saving the unhashed password `password` instead of `password_hash`. This can be accomplished using [`ActiveRecord::beforeSave()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave%28%29-detail) to set the password value to `password_hash`. You should also use a different name for the password field in the form say `password_field`.

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if(isset($this->password_field)) 
        $this->password = Security::generatePasswordHash($this->password_field);
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Comment: my user model extending  \yii\db\ActiveRecord, but when i use beforeSave method it is not invoking beforeSave() from model, in UserController i'm using $model->save() method

Answer (score 5):

Few things are unclear but i hope to give you enough information to resolve your issue and i don't have enough rep to add a comment.

When using the `setPassword` you will get a string larger than your current `VARCHAR(32)` setup in the database table. Make it at least `VARCHAR(64)`. Example string that will be returned is `$2a$12$FbbEBjZVTLPZg4D/143KWu0ptEXL7iEcXpxJ.MNMl8/6L0SV5FR6u`. Adjust this also in your model to make the validation work.

You will need to tell your model to use the password hashing when saving the model.

This example comes from the `Yii2/Advanced` app. As part of your controller for user creation. They send the request to `$model->signup()` in the advanced app ([Frontend Sitecontroller example](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php))

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Adjust your current model to hash the password before saving or add a complete new function, they use 'signup' in the example ([Model for signup example](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/SignupForm.php)). After the model field validation has been successfull they process the request. Change the following fields according to your table.

```
public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->save();
        return $user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

For debugging validation errors you can add `print_r($model->getErrors());` behind any `$model->save();`

Hope this will give you enough information to get your problem fixed.